# How can I update my iMac G4?

Tags: macos, software-update

I have an iMac G4 and I want to update it to OS X 10.4.
I checked and all is OK, but I don't know were can I download the install DVD!
Can I use this https://archive.org/details/macosx10.4tigerretaildvd?
If yes, then would doing so be illegal?

Comment: That's a retail 10.4 DVD.  You need to look at something like MacTracker and see whether the machine you have was supported by 10.4 retail, or whether it required one of the supplemental updates.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you're supposed to buy the DVD from Apple - upgrades weren't free in those days - practically, I doubt anyone cares any more.

Comment: i had checked and it's compatible. I don't think that they still sell macOS Tiger install DVD

Comment: FYI, some iMac G4 models are compatible with OS X 10.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, all G4 iMacs came bundled with a version before Tiger 10.4, so a retail Tiger disk should work.

As to legality: technically, the software is © Apple, and should not be copied and distributed, but as they no longer offer it for sale, you're not 'doing them' out of any money that they would otherwise earn from the sale.

Apple have shown a relaxed attitude to hobbyists using old computers (and even to the Hackintosh community, whom they have not pursued in the courts).